# Powershell or CMD - I want to run two commands at the same time without waiting for the first command to finish

Tags: flutter, powershell, cmd, flutter-test, flutter-integration-test

I would like to run two commands (it doesn't matter if it's in powershell or cmd). The commands are as follows. I try to run both at the same time but because chromedriver needs to be running - it hangs forever and never reaches the second command.

- chromedriver --port=4444
- flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart --browser-name=chrome --release --no-headless

I am following the documentation here (towards the bottom of the page)
[Flutter integration testing](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) (but this isn't really that important for my question - just an FYI on what I was doing)

I keep googling for "how to run two commands" but the answers I usually get are to use "&" or "&&" but in my case this doesn't work as chromedriver will just stay open whilst it executes.

Thanks,

Michael Smith

Comment: `Start-Job` to run on a separate thread. Can also use `Start-Process` to run the commands in a separate powershell instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMD you should try

```
start "" chromedriver --port=4444
```